# LatLng.latitude and LatLng.longitude cant be used because not specific values

Tags: java, android, google-maps

got an error at line "Location.distanceBetween(LatLng.latitude, LatLng.longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);" LatLng.latitude and LatLng.longitude cant be used because not specific values.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback{//DirectionFinderListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
//private Button btnFindPath;
//private EditText etOrigin;
//private EditText etDestination;
private List<Marker> originMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
private List<Marker> destinationMarkers = new ArrayList<>();
// private List<Marker>  = new ArrayList<>();

Circle shape;
Marker marker;
//private List<Polyline> polylinePaths = new ArrayList<>();
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
long minDistance = 15;

float[] distance = new float[2];

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    //btnFindPath = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFindPath);
    //etOrigin = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etOrigin);
    //etDestination = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDestination);

    /*btnFindPath.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendRequest();
        }
    });*/
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    LatLng hcmus = new LatLng(3.719639, 103.123972); //3.719639, 103.123972
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(hcmus, 18));
    originMarkers.add(mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("IBM CoE")
            .position(hcmus)));

    Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
            .center(new LatLng(3.719639, 103.123972))
            .radius(10000)
            .strokeColor(Color.RED)
            .fillColor(Color.BLUE));

    LocationManager lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    double latitude = location.getLatitude();

    private final LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            longitude = location.getLongitude();
            latitude = location.getLatitude();
        }
    };

    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2000, 10, locationListener);


    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        return;
    }
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Location.distanceBetween(LatLng.latitude, LatLng.longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude,distance);

    if ( distance[0] <= circle.getRadius())
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You are in radius location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(this, "You are not in radius location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    /*if (destinationMarkers == ) { //equation

        Intent main = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(main);
    }
     else {   Toast.makeText(this, "You are not in radius location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }*/
}
```

How to get current Location latitude and longitude

Answer (score 1):

See the parameter of [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#distanceBetween(double,%20double,%20double,%20double,%20float[])) of distanceBetween method. It results distance in meter between two locations and it takes parameters like this,

```
startLatitude   double: the starting latitude
startLongitude  double: the starting longitude
endLatitude     double: the ending latitude
endLongitude    double: the ending longitude
results         float: an array of floats to hold the results
```

As its clearly stated, the first two parameters hold the value of first location object's Latitude and Longitude. In your case, you're referring the default [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html) object's Latitude and Longitude properties which doesn't represent any location value.

I can see you're already getting current location

```
Location location = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
double longitude = location.getLongitude();
double latitude = location.getLatitude();
```

So, this line should be like this,

```
Location.distanceBetween(latitude, longitude, circle.getCenter().latitude,circle.getCenter().longitude, distance);
```

Comment: already try but google maps has stop working when i launched the app

Comment: Its possible current latitude and longitude is yet to be fetched when google map runs. Can you post the log message when you run the code with the change I mentioned?